# How to maintain a counter variable thats value can be used in Page Init

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, postback

This subject seems to be be beaten to death and yet I still can't find an answer.

I am trying to allow users to click a button to add a usercontrol to a page. Hypothetically, they can do this as many times as they want. I know I need to recreate these controls on Postback, and am trying to do this in Page Init so that viewstate can give them back their values in page load.

My problem is I have no idea how to keep a running counter that I can use in Init to recreate the proper number of controls the user has put on the page. Viewstate is not available in Init so I can't just use a hidden field where I could increment or decrement the value. I also cannot use Session variables. I am not allowed to use them in this particular project.

As an FYI, I'm adding and deleting these usercontrols successfully right now when I do it on Page Load. But, the fields within the usercontrol do not retain their values consistently between postbacks.

Answer (score -1):

You can always keep this count in the client, and add it to the URL for instance.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Do you have an example? I'm not quite sure how this would work.